# Linux: Emulating memory via signal handler

Tags: c, linux, memory, segmentation-fault, emulation

I basically want to emulate memory by catching `SIGSEGV` to specific locations. These locations will be zero-permission-mapped using `mmap()`. Performance is something that doesn't matter too much as it's just an experiment. I figured out how to figure out the memory location accessed in the handler, but I am stuck trying to actually figure out weather a read of a write has happened and how do simulate a successful read with fake data or how to simulate a successful write, intercepting the data written.

Can you give me any tips, or other approaches (maybe something that hasn't got anything to do with signals at all) to this problem?

I wish there was more to find about this on the wide internet, guess nobody had this kind of stupid idea before lol

Thanks

Comment: The handler will ofc only be responding to one of those predefined and guaranteed-unused memory locations. All others will still terminate the program. And since it's supposed to give the code a fake value back anyways, I don't see a problem.

Comment: For Linux, investigate `userfaultfd`.

Comment: It does not seem to allow me to see which exact address has been accessed, just the address of the start of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you mean by *simulate*. There is much more unknowns - the width of access, side effects, etc. In any case, if you would find all the missing pieces, what you are going to do next?

If you simply *simulate* an access, and return from the handler, the CPU will rerun the faulty instruction, and guess what? - it will immediately segfault again.

**Now opening a can of worms.**

You may try to

- find what the instruction pointer in `ucontext` points to
- decode the pointed instruction, *simulate* it the way you want (tricky)

  - keeping in mind that the instruction may have side effects (like setting/clearing flags, or modifying registers)
- figure out what the nex instruction would be (doubleplustricky)
- doctor `ucontext` appropriately
- and return from the handler.

I am sure there will be too many corner cases.

**Now opening another can of worms**

Another approach, a more debugger-like, is to implement a single-step handler. In a segfault handler

- back up the protected area, and prepare it for a read
- remove the protection
- enable a single-step flag in `ucontext`
- get ready to handle the single-step exception
- return

and in a single-step handler

- compare the protected area with a back-up. If they are different, it was a write access; do what is deem necessary
- restore the protection
- return